# making simple Calculator using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jbutton

i am making a simple calculator using Net beans but there is a problem in between Button and text field .
i want that thing where i click button "1" after clicking one it supposed to show one but nothing showing and please help how to setup "+" button in between them help please.
    /*
     * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */

```
/**
 *
 * @author Administrator
 */
public class Calculator extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Calculator
     */
    public Calculator() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton12 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton10 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton11 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton9 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton8 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton7 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton13 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Rajendra Calculator", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP));

        jButton12.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton12.setText("=");

        jButton10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton10.setText("0");

        jButton11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton11.setText("+");
        jButton11.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton11ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton9.setText("9");

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("1");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.JTextField.RIGHT);
        jTextField1.setText("0");
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton8.setText("8");

        jButton5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton5.setText("5");

        jButton4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton4.setText("4");
        jButton4.setToolTipText("");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("2");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton7.setText("7");

        jButton6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton6.setText("6");

        jButton13.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton13.setText("Clear");

        jButton3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jButton3.setText("3");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton4)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton5)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton6))
                        .addComponent(jTextField1)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton3))
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton7)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton8)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton9)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton11, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 65, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton10, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addComponent(jButton12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jButton13, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 66, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 42, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4)
                    .addComponent(jButton5)
                    .addComponent(jButton6))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton7)
                    .addComponent(jButton8)
                    .addComponent(jButton9))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton10)
                    .addComponent(jButton13))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton11)
                    .addComponent(jButton12))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(18, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
 jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+"1");
    }                                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText()+"2"); // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    int valA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
int valB = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());        // TODO add your handling code here:

        int valC = valA+valB;
        jTextField1.append(Integer.toString(valC));
        jTextField1.append("\n");    // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calculator().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton10;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton11;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton12;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton13;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton7;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton8;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. (copied from flag dialog)

Comment: i just wanted to know ...How to set up JButton ..where i press it and it shows "1" on textField....and how to set up JButton for "+" where it worth for addition?? may hope you understand..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...How to set up JButton ..where i press it and it shows "1" on textField

Typically, in cases like this the text field would be non-editable so you can effectively "append" text to the text field by using:

```
textField.replaceSelection("1");
```

However, the better approach is to share an Action for all the buttons:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class ButtonCalculator extends JPanel
{
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private JTextField display;

    public ButtonCalculator()
    {
        Action numberAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                display.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        display = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable( false );
        display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        buttons = new JButton[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            buttons[i] = button;
            buttonPanel.add( button );

            //  Support Key Bindings

            KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(text);
            InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            inputMap.put(pressed, text);
            button.getActionMap().put(text, numberAction);
        }

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(5, 10, 5, 10) );
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Calculator");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new ButtonCalculator() );
        frame.setResizable( false );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`JTextField` does not have an `append` method, it only has a `setText` method.

If you really need "appending" capability, then you need to use a `JTextArea` instead...

Take some time and read through [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) and [Using text components](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html).

Personally, I would throw out the form designer and get to know the API as well as you can, it will give a greater appreciation of what the form designer does and when it's appropriate to use it...IMHO

**Updated**

Your basic flow is off.  A user enters a value and press "+", you then try and add the value in the text field to itself and re-apply the value back to the text field...This means that it is unlikely that the user will actually ever be able to sum two values together.

Instead, you should be storing the value in the text field in some kind of `List` each time the user clicks the "+" button and clearing the text field for the next value.  When they press the "=" button, you should simply iterate over this list and put the result into the textfield and clear the list...

For example...

```
private List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(25);
/*...*/

private void jButton11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        int valA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
        values.add(valA);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    jTextField1.setText("");
}
```

You haven't provided an `actionPerformed` method for the "=" button, but it's contents would look something like...

```
int result = 0;
for (int value : values) {
    result += value;
}
values.clear();
jTextField1.setText(Integer.toString(result));
```

Comment: will you please make a program for me for this calculator?

Comment: It could use `jTextField1.setText(jTextField1.getText().concat(String string));`.

Comment: @RajendraArora No....

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Last time I checked, `JTextField` didn't support new lines...

Comment: please make a program for me where i could understand better please.

Comment: @MadProgrammer append and interpreting new line characters is two different things, no?

Comment: please make a calculator program for me, i'm a beginner in netbeans please help where i could understand better..

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Not in this context.  The reason why I mention it is because that's what the OP is doing, they are trying to append a value and a new line to a `JTextField`, which would seem to suggest that they really want a `JTextArea`

Comment: @RajendraArora Don't, just don't. It is not appropriate and not welcome.  If you continue, I will simply delete the answer.  You've dumped a bunch of code on us, without highlighting the particular issues you are having and are now expecting us to provide our time freely to you to solve your problems for what appears to be an assignment.  Show some effort first, but only expect guideance.  Simply asking for a copy-paste answer is not going to make you a better developer.  You need to have the ability take ideas and mould them to your needs

Comment: @MadProgrammer I still don't agree but no problem. I think the best answer would be JTextField does not have an `append(String str)` method and don't interpret and/or support multi-line.

Comment: well Thanxs for encouraging to me..@MadProgrammer..

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento I don't disagree with your intentions, just the context.  After spending some time with code it would seem that the OP doesn't really want to be appending the values to the text field any way (or at least not in the way that they are ;))